# React HOC: Redirect bug when changing from account type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I created a higher order component `WithAccess` to check if a user has the right permissions (logged in and account role) to enter some protected routes. I'm using the hoc like this:

```
const authCondition = authUser => !!authUser;

<Route path="/a" component={WithAccess(authCondition, "admin")(Admin)} />
<Route path="/u" component={WithAccess(authCondition, "user")(User)} />
```

*Admin and User are two functional components with routes.*

WithAccess contains an onAuthStateChanged listener. Inside the listener I'm checking the role of the user (I'm setting a custom claim 'role' when the user is created). If this matches the prop 'role' that was passed down, isLoading is set to false and the component will render. Otherwise the user gets redirected back to the login page.

```
const WithAccess = (condition, role) => Component => {
  class withAccess extends React.Component {
    state = {
      isLoading: true
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      Auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
        if (user) {
          const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult(true);
          if (condition(user) && idTokenResult.claims.role === role)
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
          else this.props.history.push(`/login`);
        }
      });
    }

    render() {
      return !this.state.isLoading ? (
        <Component />
      ) : (
        <PageLoader label="Checking user..." />
      );
    }
  }

  return withRouter(withAccess);
};

export default WithAccess;
```

This is working. However when I switch from an admin account to an user account or visa versa, WithAccess is passing down the previous role.

To clear things up I remade the login/register part in a code sandbox: [link to code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pk3rqnl3o0).

Best way to reproduce:

1. Go to the login page and register a new user
2. Logout when you are redirected to the user dashboard
3. Login as admin with email: admin@example.com and password: 123456
4. 'Login' will change to 'Dashboard' in the navigation but you will stay on the login page (In fact, you get redirected to /a/dashboard but WithAccess is redirecting you back immediately)

I'm trying to understand why WithAccess is passing down the previous role when switching from account type but couldn't figured it out yet.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but it is working properly as expected! I am not redirected from the dashboard.

Comment: Well that's kind of good and bad news haha. Maybe it's something specific in my browser

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a memory leak in your application! Quite tricky to catch these :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/k3218vqq8o

> In your With Access HOC you have to unlisten to the firebase onAuth callback.

Always remember to cleanup the component if you add a listener somewhere!

```
componentDidMount() {
  //Retain a reference to the unlistener callback
  this.fireBaseAuthUnlistener = Auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
    if (user) {
      const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult(true);
      console.log("ID Token claims: ", idTokenResult.claims);
      console.log("ROLE : ", role);
      if (condition(user) && idTokenResult.claims.role === role) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        this.props.history.push(`/login`);
      }
    }
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  //Unlisten when unmounting!
  this.fireBaseAuthUnlistener && this.fireBaseAuthUnlistener();
  this.fireBaseAuthUnlistener = undefined;
}
```

Comment: I guess this is it. Added the unlistener and tried a few times to register and login with the different account types. No error so far!

Comment: @Thore Yes most probably it is! Don't forget to mark as answered if this answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should vastly simplify your route structure, where you first wrap your authenticated routes in a `ProtectedRoutes` HOC. This route only allows authenticated (signed in) users to view it. Then add another `RequireAdmin` HOC to check if the `role` is `admin`. If not, it redirects to a `NotFound` page.

An authenticated user has access to `/u/dashboard` but when they click on the `Admin Dashboard` link it shows a `NotFound` page. However, the admin has access to both!

To test:

- click `Login`
- sign in as `testuser123@example.com` with password `123456`
- when redirected, try to access `Admin Dashboard`
- redirects to `NotFound` page
- click `Go Back`
- click `Dashboard`
- click `Logout`
- click `Login` again.
- sign in as `admin@example.com` with password `123456`
- when redirected, click `User Dashboard` and `Admin Dashboard` (both work)

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Protected Routes Example]

---

**containers/ProtectedRoutes**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Navigation from "../../components/Website/Navigation";

class ProtectedRoutes extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
   if (isEmpty(this.props.user) || !this.props.user.email) {
      this.props.history.push("/notfound");
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
      this.props.history.push("/notfound");
    }
  };

  render = () =>
    this.props.user.email ? (
      <Fragment>
        <Navigation />
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>
    ) : null;
}

export default connect(state => ({ user: state.user }))(
  withRouter(ProtectedRoutes)
);
```

**containers/RequireAdmin**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class RequireAdmin extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (isEmpty(this.props.user) || this.props.user.role !== "admin") {
      this.props.history.push("/notfound");
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
      this.props.history.push("/notfound");
    }
  };

  render = () =>
    isEmpty(this.props.user) || this.props.user.role === "admin"
      ? this.props.children
      : null;
}

export default connect(state => ({ user: state.user }))(
  withRouter(RequireAdmin)
);
```

**routes** (main)

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../containers/ProtectedRoutes";

import Admin from "../components/Admin";
import Home from "../pages/Website/Home";
import NotFound from "../pages/Website/NotFound";
import LoginForm from "../containers/LoginForm";
import RegisterForm from "../containers/RegisterForm";
import User from "../components/User";

const Routes = () => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterForm} />
      <Route exact path="/notfound" component={NotFound} />
      <ProtectedRoutes>
        <Route path="/u" component={User} />
        <Route path="/a" component={Admin} />
      </ProtectedRoutes>
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

export default Routes;
```

**components/User** (user protected routes)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "../../pages/User/Dashboard";
import NotFound from "../../pages/Website/NotFound";

const User = ({ match }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${match.url}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}`} component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Fragment>
);

export default User;
```

**components/Admin** (admin protected routes)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import RequireAdmin from "../../containers/RequireAdmin";
import Dashboard from "../../pages/Admin/Dashboard";
import NotFound from "../../pages/Website/NotFound";

const Admin = ({ match }) => (
  <RequireAdmin>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${match.url}/dashboard`} component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}`} component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </RequireAdmin>
);

export default Admin;
```